# How can I access this array that has been output from a serialized source?

Tags: arrays, simplexml

I'm having some trouble accessing this array that is being output by simplexml - simplexml_load_file. The result of the output is this:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#213 (6) { ["DeliveryId"]=> string(14) "DELIVERYID_001" } }
```

It's being printed from a parsed XML file, and shows data. There is only one result at current.

I'm aiming to get the elements - [DeliveryId], [GameName], etc. How would I do so? I've tried $return['item'] and $return->item, but neither are reporting back. I've also tried $return[0].

Comment: please edit your question and post the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer which was somewhat convoluted. To access this array I had to use $Array[0]->Item.